# Moving the mouse over a terminal window generates escape sequences

Tags: ssh, tmux, mouse

When using `tmux` over a ssh connection, if I launch a program to keep open, I  run into troubles when I move my mouse inside the `tmux` window:

> ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B
>   ^[^[

This hangs my executable. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why would you want to use a mouse in the first place?

Comment: I don't, it's a side effect of me working on windows :( hope I will run away soon

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using to run ssh in?